# How do you press 2 keys at the same time with python without it alternating between them and holding them

Tags: python, keyboard

When I try pressing 2 keys at the same time it types it fine but in a game it shows that it stops pressing one when the other one is pressed and im trying to find a way to keep both pressed the entire time until the if statement is done

```
import time
import keyboard
import serial

        if dataPacket.startswith(b"4"):
            keyboard.press("d")
            keyboard.press("w")  
            print ("yo1")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            keyboard.release("d")
            keyboard.release("w")
        if dataPacket.startswith(b"5"):
            keyboard.press("a")
            keyboard.press("w")   
            print ("yo2")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            keyboard.release("a")
            keyboard.release("w")
```

Everything except when it tries pressing 2 at once works fine and holds it but when it does try press both at a time it alternates and only presses one at a time.

Ive tryed pyautogui hotkey and that didnt work
Ive tried keyboard.send("d+w", do_release=False)
Ive tried keyboard.press("a, d")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presser.py`

```py
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.press("d+w")
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.release("d+w")
```

`logger.py`

```py
import keyboard
import sys

def on_key_event(e):
    if e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        keys_pressed.add(e.name)
    elif e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_UP:
        keys_pressed.discard(e.name)

keys_pressed = set()
keyboard.hook(on_key_event)

print("Press 'Esc' to exit.", end='\r')
sys.stdout.flush()

try:
    while True:
        pressed_keys = ' + '.join(keys_pressed)
        sys.stdout.write(f"\rKeys pressed: {pressed_keys: <50}")
        sys.stdout.flush()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("\nExiting...")
```

I've tried this and it works, if your game is not picking it up it might be that game's problem.

GIF of it working:
[image]